# angular component name affecting css

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular 1.5 component. I have created a component and used it inside the template

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <a>Some action here</a>
    </li>

    <li>
       <my-component></my-component>
    </li>
</ul>
```

inside this my-component I have code for

```
<a></a>
```

and css properties are defined as ul li a, because of the component name I am unable to access the element in css using the above selector.

Is there any way out for this ?

Comment: Can you show your directive code

Answer (score 1):

You can - in your css file - do:

```
my-component {
   //your styles
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Lw18LtUVuHfSZU05b6R9?p=preview[plunker, see last component](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lw18LtUVuHfSZU05b6R9?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I have face this problem earlier, just try to add

```
replace: true
```

property on your directive.
hope it will also work for you.

Comment: Actually I am not using directive, I am using component from angular 1.5